# macOS Ventura - Cannot update macOS 13.0.1 to 13.1

Tags: macos, software-update, ventura

I'm having issue updating macOS from 13.0.1 to 13.1, see the screen recording below:

[image]

When I clicked on `update` -> `agree`, nothing happened, no update was requested, it was like I was stuck in a loop.

I tried restarting the computer, but it didn't help.

What could I possibly try to fix this issue?

Additional info:

- I have Xcode command line tools installed and it's up-to-date, version: `Command Line Tools for Xcode-14.2`.
- I don't have Xcode app installed.

Update: I tried to use `softwareupdate` but it stuck too:

```
❯ softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: SafariTechPreview-160
    Title: Safari Technology Preview, Version: 160, Size: 124475KiB, Recommended: YES, 
* Label: macOS Ventura 13.1-22C65
    Title: macOS Ventura 13.1, Version: 13.1, Size: 1147851K, Recommended: YES, Action: restart, 
❯ sudo softwareupdate -i "macOS Ventura 13.1-22C65"
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Downloading macOS Ventura 13.1

Downloaded: macOS Ventura 13.1
```

Comment: Try running `softwareupdate` in the Terminal.

Comment: @lhf tried that and got stuck too,  please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are experiencing issues when it lists multiple updates, try installing just one update at a time.

You can click "More Info..." and refine the list to just the OS update, then try.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too.

The issue I had was with Xcode command line tools needing an update.

I had to go to AppStore and complete that update first.

Comment: I guess you probably could have clicked "more info" and installed at least the macOS update by itself first?

Comment: @Radarm - No I could not. I tried several times. I had to do the Xcode update first

Comment: More info just keeps the loop as shown in the question's gif

Comment: I don't have Xcode app installed, what should I do?
Please see updated question.

Comment: I had this issue but forget exactly how to fix. But I definitely needed to install Xcode command line before anything else - try selecting that in more info on its own

Answer (score 3):

below code helped me fixed this issue:

```
    softwareupdate -l
    softwareupdate -i "macOS Ventura 13.1-22C65"
```

Comment: You might have to try `softwareupdate -l` several times before it realizes there's an update actually available, per [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/452674/34759).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. An update was not found at first, and after a few tries of running `softwareupdate -l` in Terminal, it was found.

When downloading, it was stuck at 15% and so forth so I had to start over with the same loop. I had to download the macOS Ventura installer again (12 GB) and install it. On my Mac Studio with 10 cores, it took just 15 minutes or so.

Comment: Same, weirdly enough the _first_ `softwareupdate -l`, like the UI, found no available updates. But! The second time I ran it, it did. *So* weird and buggy.